# Inserting information in the sql lite database not working

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

The texts that were already stored in the database are displaying without any problem. But new inserted data not showing. I think "Nothing will be displayed by adding new text, as if the insertion action was not performed.". I don't know why it's not working.Please help...

My DatabaseHandler class

```
 public class databaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    private Context main_context;
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "word.sqlite";
    private static String DB_TBL_BOOKS = "word";
    private static String DB_TBL_SETTING = "setting";
    private static final  int DB_version = 1;
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "content";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public databaseHandler(Context con)
    {



        super(con, DB_NAME, null, DB_version);

        main_context = con;
        DB_PATH = con.getCacheDir().getPath() + "/" +DB_NAME;

    }
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDB();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE word (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , title VARCHAR, content VARCHAR DEFAULT null)";
        db.execSQL(query);
        Log.d("log","table Created");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w("tag", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS word");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private boolean db_exist() {

        File f = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (f.exists())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean copyDB() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);
            InputStream in =main_context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buffer , 0, ch);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("amirmessage", "error in 84 -> " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }



    public void open()
    {
        if (db_exist())
        {
            try {
                File temp = new File(DB_PATH);
                db =SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(temp.getAbsolutePath() , null ,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("amirmessage", "error in 100 -> " + e.toString());

            }

        }
        else {
            if (copyDB())
            {
                open();
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        db.close();
    }
    //---------




    public List<HashMap<String , Object>> getresultOfSerach()
    {
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DB_TBL_BOOKS  ,null);
        List<HashMap<String , Object>> all_data = new ArrayList<>();

       try {
           while ( result.moveToNext())
           {
               HashMap<String , Object> temp = new HashMap<>();
               temp.put("id" , result.getString(0));
               temp.put("content" , result.getString(2));


               temp.put("title" , result.getString(1));



               all_data.add(temp);
               Log.d("update","Query: ");

           }
       } finally
        {
            result.close();
        }



        return all_data;
    }


    public void addcontent(String state, String title)
    {

        ContentValues cv  = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("content", state);
        cv.put("title", title);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();


            db.insert(DB_TBL_BOOKS,null,cv);

        Toast.makeText(main_context,state+title , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
 }
```

My Activity insert code is here

```
public class addcontent extends AppCompatActivity 

  {

    private databaseHandler db;
    public String title1;
    public String content;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addcontent);
        db = new databaseHandler(getBaseContext());
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        EditText etcontent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText ettitle1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        title1=ettitle1.getText().toString();
        content=etcontent.getText().toString();


    }

      public void onbtnadd(View v)
    {

        db.open();
        db.addcontent( content,title1);

        db.close();

    }
}
```

My MainActivity  code to Show information is here

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private databaseHandler db;
private ListView resultListView;
private List<HashMap<String , Object>> resultsbooks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),addcontent.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    resultListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.catListview);
    db = new databaseHandler(getBaseContext());
    showresultOfSerarch();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void onbtnfind()
{
    resultListView.setAdapter(null);

    String serachBy;

    serachBy = "author";


    String query =" ";


    showresultOfSerarch();

}
  public void showresultOfSerarch() 
{
    db.open();

    resultsbooks = db.getresultOfSerach();
    db.close();


    String[] from = {"title","content"};
    int[] to = {R.id.txttitle,  R.id.txtcontent};

    SimpleAdapter adp = new SimpleAdapter(
            getBaseContext(), resultsbooks, R.layout.tbl_contest_row, from, to
    );
    resultListView.setAdapter(adp);
 }
```

}

Comment: show logcat please

Comment: log Does not show anything,Even an error is not given

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: no,Does not exist

Comment: Don't pass solution in question, it should remain a question without any solved indications, instead either mark with green checkmark the answer that was useful or pass your own answer.

Comment: *SOLVED :using db = this.getReadableDatabase() in the getresultOfSerach() in DatabaseHandler class*. this was the indication by OP in edit of question, if you pass an answer you can flag this comment as obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to say, please follow coding guidelines.

You have made no provision to display data inserted in 'word' table.

Your data insertion logic is working fine.
Once your data gets added in 'word' table, try reading values. You can make following changes to read values.

```
public void onbtnadd() {
    db.open();
    db.addcontent(content, title1);
    Cursor cursor = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from word", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // get all records inserted in 'word' table here
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U have done correct but a mistake.

Can u change ur class file

Change according  for ur field ids

```
public class AddContent extends AppCompatActivity

{
        private DatabaseHandler db;
    public String title1;
    public String content;
    EditText etcontent;
    EditText ettitle1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_content);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getBaseContext());
//        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        Button btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        etcontent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_text1);
        ettitle1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_text2);

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                title1 = ettitle1.getText().toString();
                content = etcontent.getText().toString();
                onbtnadd(v);

            }
        });


    }

    public void onbtnadd(View v) {
        db.open();
        db.addcontent(content, title1);
        db.close();

    }
```

Comment: Ur mistake is getting the value on the oncreate time.. So change the  btnclick time then working fine.

Comment: check it but not working,Listview does not show anything

Comment: are u debug it get db.getresultOfSerach() return list size check inside value or not

Comment: Follow this link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/   clear of  CRUD (Create,Read,Update and Delete)

Answer (score 0):

You can add return to `addcontent` instead of void method to understand insertion is working or not..

```
public float addcontent(String state, String title)
{

    float insert_result = 0.0f;
    ContentValues cv  = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("content", state);
    cv.put("title", title);
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    insert_result = db.insert(DB_TBL_BOOKS,null,cv);

    Toast.makeText(main_context,state+title , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return insert_result;

}
```

then you can call it  and get value on onClick event like this

```
public void onbtnadd(View v) {

    title1 = ettitle1.getText().toString();
    content = etcontent.getText().toString();

    db.open();
    float result = db.addcontent(content, title1);
    if(result>0){
       Toast.makeText(main_context,"Insert Successful!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
       Toast.makeText(main_context,"Insert Failed!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    db.close();

}
```

### Update

To read database create a method like

```
/*
Prepare BD To Read
 */
private void read() {
    if (db != null) {
        if (!db.isOpen()) {
            db = getReadableDatabase();
        }
    } else {
        db = getReadableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Then edit your `getresultOfSerach()` to show data

```
public List<HashMap<String , Object>> getresultOfSerach()
{

    read();

    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DB_TBL_BOOKS  ,null);
    List<HashMap<String , Object>> all_data = new ArrayList<>();

    String id = "";
    String contact = "";
    String title = "";

    try {
        if(result!=null) {
            while (result.moveToNext()) {
                HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>();


                id =  result.getString(0);
                contact =  result.getString(2);
                title =  result.getString(1);

                temp.put("id", id);
                temp.put("content", contact);
                temp.put("title", title);

                all_data.add(temp);
                Log.e("data ", id + "-"+ contact +"-"+ title);

            }
        }
    } finally
    {
        result.close();
    }

    return all_data;
}
```

Call this method inside your activity like this

```
public void showData() {
    db.getresultOfSerach();
}
```

Comment: Insert Successful! But nothing is displayed